# remove adjacent list elements based on condition?

Tags: python

i want remove right hand side value if difference between adjacent elements is less than 0.20, so I am doing this

```
a  = [183.4, 183.3 182.1, 182.75]
a  = [183.4, 182.1, 182.75] # what I want


for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]):
    if abs(i-j) <= 0.20:
        a.remove(j)
print(a)
```

but the output is

```
[183.4, 182.75]
```

Comment: Don't remove elements from a list you're iterating over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove elements from a list you're iterating over. You could use a slice for both inputs of `zip()`: that will create a copy so you won't run into the same problem.

```
for i, j in zip(a[:-1], a[1:]):
    if abs(i-j) <= 0.20:
        a.remove(j)
```

which gives

```
[183.4, 182.1, 182.75]
```

Alternatively, invert the condition and build a new list.

```
a_new = a[0:1] # Create a new list with the first element of a
for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]):
    if abs(i-j) > 0.20: # Append j to the new list if the difference is greater
        a_new.append(j)
```

Note that this doesn't take into account the case when *multiple consecutive pairs of elements* are within your threshold. For example: `a = [183.4, 183.3, 183.15, 182.1, 182.75]`, this will remove both `183.3` and `183.15`.

If you want the minimum difference between consecutive elements in your result to be 0.2, simply compare with the last element of `a_new` and add the current element if it satisfies your condition.

```
a = [183.4, 183.3, 183.15, 182.1, 182.75]
a_new = a[0:1]

for i in a[1:]:
    if abs(a_new[-1] - i) > 0.2:
        a_new.append(i)
```

And this gives `[183.4, 183.15, 182.1, 182.75]`